# Modify PHP SoapClient to use https rather than http for getting xsd schema

Tags: php, soap-client

I'm using SoapClient to connect to a WSDL service, and the `schemaLocation` in the WSDL is wrongly set with a `http://` address which I think should be a `https://` address.

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://...

I can fetch the schema with curl using `https://`

I cannot modify the wsdl, so I'm trying to figure out if I can make SoapClient call https:// instead when fetching the schema, to see if this solves the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not uncommon to have to change wrong values in WSDL files (unfortunately). The way to this is by deriving new classes from `SoapClient` and overloading its methods. In your case make new class and fix WSDL in its constructor: download WSDL file, change `http` to `https` in proper places and pass it to base `SoapClient` constructor.

Comment: You should really provide code samples with these sorts of things if you can.